# display only % in jqplot chart

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am integrating jqplot jquery chart plugin into my rails application. In the example of jqplot it is mentioned

```
var data = [
    ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 

  ];
```

But when the chart renders it is showing as percentages. I need to know how these values is converted to percentages so that I can apply that calculation in my rails application also.

Comment: Your chart is a pie chart? If so, I think jqplot calculate the ratio of each slice over the total : heavy industry = 12, retail = 9, light industry = 14. Total = (12+9+14) 35. Thus heavy industry = 12/35*100 = 34.3%, retail = 9/35*100 = 25.7%, light industry = 40%.

Comment: Okay.. Thats correct. Is there a way to display the data that I provide there.. like 12%, 9%, 14%

Comment: So your pie chart is having a blank slice with respect to the 65% remaining?

Comment: No No.. I will make the necessary calculations in my rails application and make it total 100%.Like 50%, 25%, 25%.. I just need to know how would I display those values. I know that there is a option as dataLabels: 'value'. But I need to apend % symbol also in that values.

Answer (score 0):

By default, labels show the percentage of the slice. The corresponding option is `showDataLabels` (set to true or false to show/hide percentage of the slice).

See [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php) for further documentation about pie charts and donut charts.